# How can I make a get request in Node.js to see how many bytes a collection use in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't want to see the length of the collection, I need the amount of bytes and then I want to make a get request to use it on my client side... Anyone can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to maybe use the `.stats()` method.

If you want the size of your collection in bytes,
use `db.collection.dataSize()`.

Comment: Thank you! I found that my problem was that I was connection to MongoDB through mongoose, I need to connect with MongoClient for the .stats() to work.